# Freebsd Box hangs on boot loader

Tags: freebsd

I have a freebsd box that seems to not want to boot past the boot loader.

It wont go past the initial boot loader phase and just lists the version number for the boot loader(btx loader). It hangs there. I am not a fluent freebsd admin and decent at command line, however I can tell clearly it wont get past and boot past the disk. Loaded up rescue cd, mounted the drive. Couldnt get fsck going without seg faulting

How do i get this fixed? I have a live cd.... just curious which route to take.

Comment: fsck is seg faulting? I would run a disk check off of the live CD and see if your disk is corrupted. Would explain the non-booting - esp if it stopped after working and there were no changes.

Comment: Yes it will segfault on the live cd...

Comment: First specify version and architecture of FreeBSD you are trying to load.
Then explain when/afterwhat it happened for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Does the live CD work enough that you can run memcheck?   What did memcheck say?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like memory corruption (as djangofan said), or a driver/hardware error in the drive controller. What kind of hardware is the machine running on?